# DateRangePicker sets value to current date if no value provided

Tags: jquery, html, daterangepicker

In my web application I am using one of the datepickers hosted at [daterangepicker](http:////cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js) and my webpage is retrieving its value from database as I don't have any value for the particular input field daterange picker is setting it to default current date.
All I want is to set it to nothing if no value is set for the particular input field.
Right now I am using this piece of code to set value for input field with id activeTill.

```
input type="text" name="activeTill" class="form-control" style="width:150px;" value="<?php echo $row['news_active_till']; ?>" id="dateTill"/>
```

**JS**

```
$('input[name="activeTill"]').daterangepicker(

            {
                singleDatePicker: true,
                showDropdowns: true,
                locale: {
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                }
            }, 

            function(start, end, label) {
              // alert($("#dateTill").val());
            });
```

Comment: Hey! Were you able to solve this issue? I am facing the same issue..